# Replace dataframe entries with another dataframe (series?) entry? vectorize? compression?

Tags: python, list, pandas, replace, dataframe

I have a function defined which performs the task I want, but it's horrendously slow. For a `DataFrame (df1=pd.read(file1))` with header `'raw_data'`, I currently cycle through each string using `.iterows` and send each entry to a function which strips and lowers and then uses `str.replace(row['replacethis'],row['withthis'])` where `'replacethis'` and `'withthis'` are columns in a second `DataFrame ((df2=pd.read(file2))`.

However, this is extremely slow, taking a couple of days for a very large number of elements of file1/file2. I have been looking for solutions for several hours/days and I've tried using `series.str.replace` with list compression to no avail with something like:

```
'raw_data'=[[x['raw_data'].replace(y['replacethis'],y['withthis']) for y in df2.iterrows()] for x in df1.iterrows()]
```

Can anyone provide any guidance or advice? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: after stripping and lower casing does the string match exactly `replacethis` or does it just contain `replacethis` string content?

Comment: for one version of the function its an exact match (i use if str == row['raw_data'] in the function), and for some it's a substring...

Comment: Well for the substring part are you expecting 1 or more than 1 match and also for the exact match? For the exact matches you could just `merge` on those columns, for the other bit I don't think you can do much beyond iterating and using `str.contains` or similar

Comment: Can you provide an example and your desired output?

Comment: (where they are all series and the function cycles through them:) For the substring example: 'raw_data' is "The cat sat on the mat", 'replacethis' is "cat", 'withthis' is "dog", desired output: "The dog sat on the mat". However, there can be multiple replacements from these two lists in df2.

For the full string match: 'raw_data': "The cat sat on the mat", 'replacethis' is "The cat sat on the mat", 'withthis' is "The dog sat on the mat", desired output is "The dog sat on the mat"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is probably to use Pandas' [DataFrame.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method:

```
# The raw_data DF
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'raw_data': ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet,', 
                                 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit']})
print 'Original:'
print df1

# The replacement patterns DF
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'replacethis': ['ipsum', 'it'], 'withthis': ['doggy', 'THAT']})
pattern_dict = df2.set_index('replacethis')['withthis'].to_dict()

df1_replaced = df1.replace(pattern_dict, regex=True)
print '\nAfter Replacement:'
print df1_replaced
```

Result:

```
Original:
      raw_data
0        Lorem
1        ipsum
2        dolor
3          sit
4        amet,
5  consectetur
6   adipiscing
7         elit

After Replacement:
      raw_data
0        Lorem
1        doggy
2        dolor
3        sTHAT
4        amet,
5  consectetur
6   adipiscing
7       elTHAT
```

Comment: outstanding, thanks one million and one million again.